# Is it possible to write script plugins for VSCode similar to Sublime Text?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Sublime Text allowed writing python scripts which, upon placing within the IDE folders, were available as internal commands that could then be placed in menu, bound to a key, etc. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics

Is there something similar for VSCode?

---

For example, this file, when placed in `ST3\Data\Packages\User`  would add a `duplicate` command.

- `<binding key="ctrl+alt+d" command="duplicate"/>`
- or with `view.runCommand('duplicate')` in the console

```py
import sublime, sublimeplugin

class DuplicateCommand(sublimeplugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, view, args):
        for region in view.sel():
            if region.empty():
                line = view.line(region)
                lineContents = view.substr(line) + '\n'
                view.insert(line.begin(), lineContents)
```

Comment: You would have to write an extension that contributes the command(s).

Comment: VSC runs in a V8 environment and the plugins are written in JavaScript (Typescript)

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, this is what I hoped for, but is it possible to put simple JS/TS files like the Python snippet above and use it in the IDE?

Comment: As far as I know not. Look at the simplest example plugin on how to get the vsc module loaded. Just copy the directory of the developed extension to the VSC extension directory. Restart VSC and you can use the new command.